# Is it possible to insert amazon.com search on my website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

Is it possible to insert amazon.com search on my website. What I mean by amazon search is if you go to amazon.com and go to the search function you can type blender or whatever and results show. I am looking to insert that search function on my amazon store but not sure if possible. I want the item parameters to search all USA amazon all depts and results show up as Amazon website search results and its the Amazon store but now everything is tagged by my amazon affialite id. If yes pls tell how; if no then pls inform so.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon's Product Advertising API.

Details: Amazon has an Associates program, wherein folks *outside* Amazon can drive traffic to Amazon and get paid if their referrals purchase stuff. For them, Amazon exposes a service, called PA-API, using which they can provide search, item details etc. functionality on *their own* website.

PA-API is available in all marketplaces. Documentation can be found [here](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html).